# Finding $a>0$ such that $a^x\geq x^a$ for all positive $x$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I want to find all real numbers $a>0$ such that for all $x>0$ we have
$$a^x\geq x^a.$$
My guess is that the only possible solution is $a=e$. But that's really all I have so far.

Comment: Why did you guess $a=e$?

Comment: Consider the turning point of $x^{1/x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find all real numbers $a>0$ such that for all $x>0$ we have $\;a^x\geq x^a\;.$

Without using derivatives, I will prove that

$e^x>x^e\quad\forall x>0\;\land\;x\ne e\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Let $\;x\;$ be any positive real number such that $\;x\ne e\;.$

Since $\;e^t>1+t\;$ for any $\;t\in\mathbb{R}\;\land\;t\ne0\;,\;$ by letting $\;t=\frac xe-1\ne0\;,\;$ we get that

$e^{\frac xe-1}>1+\frac xe-1\;,$

$e^{\frac xe-1}>\frac xe\;,$

$e^{\frac xe}>x\;,$

$e^x>x^e\;.$

I have proved the inequality $(*)$ and a trivial consequence of it is that $\;e^x\geqslant x^e\;$ for all $\;x>0\;.$

Now, I will prove that there does not exist another real number $\;a>0\;\;(a\ne e)\;$ such that $\;a^x\geqslant x^a\;$ for all $\;x>0\;.$

If there existed such real number $\;a\;$, it would result that $\;a^e\geqslant e^a\;,\;$ but from $(*)$ for $\;x=a\;$, we get that $\;e^a>a^e\;$ that is a contradiction.

Hence the only positive real number $\;a\;$ such that $\;a^x\geqslant x^a\;$ for all $\;x>0\;,\;$ is $\;a=e\;.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It amounts to showing the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln x} x\quad(x>0),$$
has a unique maximum, attained at a single point.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle a^x \ge x^a \implies x^{\frac{1}{x}} \le a^{\frac{1}{a}}$, so at which $x$ does the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ gets maximized?

Answer (score 0):

$a^x \geqslant x^a$ is equivalent to $x \ln a \geqslant a \ln x$.

So it is equivalent to $\frac{\ln x}{x} \geqslant \frac{\ln a}{a}$.

So we have to look at the function $g:x\mapsto \frac{\ln x}{x}$.

By deriving it, we get that $g$ is increasing then decreasing, with a maximum for $x=e$, where $e$ is the unique solution of the equation $\ln x = 1$ (it is unique because this last function is strictly increasing).

So $g$ as a unique maximum, and it is reached for a positive $x$.

So the only $a$ that verifies $a^x \geqslant x^a$ for all $x>0$ is $e$.

Hope it helped.

Comment: It is not true that $b\ne e$, actually $b=e$. If you calculate correctly the derivative of $g$, you can notice that $b$ is not the solution of $x\ln x=1$ but the solution of $\ln x=1$.

Comment: Sorry and thank you. I edited.